# How do I switch windows without actually opening a new one?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created an animation in xaml, and I'd like the second part to be played in a new window. I certainly could open a new one after the login animation completes and play it, but I was wondering if I could stay in the same window, but use a different xaml file.

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfAnimation1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelName"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <Label Content="_Name:"
                   Target="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxName}" />
            <TextBox Height="19"
                     Width="110"
                     Margin="18.55,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelPassword"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <Label Content="_Password:" />
            <PasswordBox Height="19"
                         Width="110" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button
            Content="Log in"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="60"
            IsDefault="True"
            Margin="0,13,0,0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanelName"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                      Value="0" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5"
                                                      Value="-381" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanelName"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                      Value="1" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5"
                                                      Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanelPassword"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                      Value="0" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5"
                                                      Value="381" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanelPassword"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                      Value="1" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5"
                                                      Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ImageProfilePicture"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5"
                                                      Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                                                      Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanelNameTitle"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                                                      Value="0" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3"
                                                      Value="1" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Rectangle x:Name="ImageProfilePicture"
                   Fill="Black"
                   Height="50"
                   Width="50"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="10,10,0,0" 
                   Opacity="0"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelNameTitle"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Opacity="0">
            <TextBlock Text="First Last name"
                       Margin="8,0,0,0"
                       FontSize="13"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Student"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why not just a UserControl?

Comment: Or [navigate to a page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx)?

Comment: If your second page/window should return a value, a PageFunction is also applicable. An example is available at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33710/WPF-PageFunction-Object. Do you need to use a new window, considering you don't *want* to use a new window?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, in the animation's Completed eventhandler I set the window's content to the new page, and played the second part in the new file. Thanks for your suggestion. The second page should be some kind of dashboard, so I think it should definitely be separated from the login stuff.

Comment: You can host a Page in a Frame.  I do it a lot to flop out content.   A Page will host in a frame but a Window will not.   But a Page is a lot like a Window.